# Dealing with clutter on user profile activity feeds

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application, timeline, activity-feed

The below image represents a sample activity feed from a taxi booking mobile app that I'm working on.

I've looked at several timeline examples on Pttrns website and came up with the following solution.

However, the detail at the bottom still bothers me slightly - it seems a bit cluttered. This bothers me. Is there anyway to better represent the information below? Its all important to have (in my opinion at least), but are there any better ways of highlighting this information to the user.

In a case where something would need to be dropped - what would you leave out.

[image]

FYI each entry on the timeline is structured as follows:

```
Full name                                                      Timestamp

Journey Made

Taxi Company Used      Mileage      Fare      Duration
```

Comment: Sarah Li is always Sarah Li. Why do you repeat this in the Sarah Li's history??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some improvements could be made:
[image]

1. **Simplicity.** Remove repeating elements. Name and photo are always the same and have no meaning in the context.
2. **Typography.** Break the lines in an right way.
3. **Search.** Clear indicate points A and B of the route for fast search.
4. **Standards.** Use standard abbreviations, `min` for minutes, not `m`.
5. **Usefulness.** Add useful functionality in a history page, like `repeat the route`, `favorite route`, etc.
6. **Minimal design.** Not sure if the mileage has sense for a user. Time and cost are tangible and concrete measures, while mileage is not.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider this, increase the line height and moving the details to a new row and highlight it with a subtle grey to make it less cluttered.

[image]

Comment: In addition, I think you should make meaningful data more visible - maybe the same font size as another text, but in any way icons should be placed into shadow. Note that now they are like letters in a text and make it different to notice. Make icons smaller and more transparent for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just a matter of minor adjustments to the spacing and alignment of the elements. These minor changes keep the essence of your design and make it feel more balanced and less cluttered.

[image: alternative for activity feed]

Answer (score 1):

One thing that hasn't been mentioned yet is the use of imagery. In all the designs up to this point, the user's avatar has taken up a considerable part of the design. In this context, the users avatar will not increase engagement.

Is it useful?

I would argue that the Avatar is only useful to taxi companies. There are a few data points that could replace this space and improve the usefulness:

1. **Taxi Company-** If I am looking at recent activity within a taxi app, it could be useful to see what companies I've used.
2. **Trip Cost-** Giving the user an easy way to scan trip cost could be a valuable replacement to the avatar.
3. **Map-** Allow a thumbnail of their route map. You could allow someone to click/tap this map and see it expand.

[Feeds form habits](https://getstream.io/activity-feed-design/#design-activity-feeds). Hopefully, some of this advice could increase the usability and habit-forming patterns that increase user engagement.